# Counting observations based on individual date ranges

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

What I am trying to do is, for each individual ("id") at each sample location ("date") to count the number of unique observations within the last 1 year as a new column ("n_sample_1y");

Hence I would like to achieve an output like this;

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id date                n_sample_1y
  <dbl> <dttm>                    <dbl>
1     3 2010-01-10 00:00:00           1
2     3 2010-02-15 00:00:00           2
3     3 2010-03-29 00:00:00           3
4     3 2010-03-29 00:00:00           3
5     3 2011-02-16 00:00:00           2
6     3 2011-06-13 00:00:00           2
```

I have been using the lubridate package to calculate the start date ("s_date") of the date range

```
mutate(s_date= date - lubridate::years(1), sample_no = match(date, unique(date)))
```

but I can't seem to progress any further.

Any tips/ideas would kindly be appreciated.
Data sample:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5), 
               date = structure(c(1220572800, 1221004800, 1269820800, 1269820800, 1274227200, 1276387200, 1279756800, 1283904000, 1286668800, 1289779200), 
               tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

nc <- ncol(df) + 1
final_df <- data.frame()

for(j in unique(df$id)){
  df1 <- df %>% filter(df$id == j)
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    
      df1[i, nc] <- length(unique(intersect(df1$date[df1$date <= df1$date[i]], df1$date[df1$date >= df1$date[i] %m-% years(1)])))
      
  }
  
  final_df <- rbind(final_df, df1)
}
```

Comment: please provide a sample of your raw dataframe with `dput(head(df, 10))`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the fast comment. I've added an sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **lubridate(), dplyr()** and **making a loop**

Install and load **lubridate and dplyr** library first.
If I understood properly your question, then here is sample data and the corresponding solution to this problem.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5), 
               date = structure(c(1220572800, 1221004800, 1269820800, 1269820800, 1274227200, 1276387200, 1279756800, 1283904000, 1286668800, 1289779200), 
               tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

nc <- ncol(df) + 1
final_df <- data.frame()

for(j in unique(df$id)){
  df1 <- df %>% filter(df$id == j)
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    
      df1[i, nc] <- length(unique(intersect(df1$date[df1$date <= df1$date[i]], df1$date[df1$date >= df1$date[i] %m-% years(1)])))
      
  }
  
  final_df <- rbind(final_df, df1)
}
```

Hope this updated code helps.. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. As I understand, this counts the number of times each date appears for each individual. What I am trying to do, is to sum the number of observations (unique dates) with values of "date" <=  the current date & >= "s_date". I.e. for each observation, I would like to count the number of observations (excluding duplicates) within a one-year interval defined by the date of the current observation.

Comment: GREAT! this exactly the count I was looking for - only performed groupwise for each id. Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm mostly familiar with the structure of dplyr. Usually I would use the group_by function to perform the calculations groupwise, but I guess this doesn't make sense here due to the structure of the loop.

Comment: Oh, I think I missed the IDs earlier. I have created a new dataset and updated the code to take care of the categories also. Check if it works now.

Comment: This is beautiful! I had a feeling that it would involve a loop in a loop. Thank you so much for the help.